# Form data not posted to next page

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using ZF2, few of my fields are created customarily due to design. While few are created via zend form. THe thing is that when i post data i get only those fields posted that are created via ZF2 form e.g my username field, gender, title. Rest of fields are not posted. Here is the snippet to my code

```
 <?php
 $form = $this->form;
 $form->prepare();


 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

?>
<div class="featureBox">
<div class="profile_address">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="address_head"><h4><?php echo $form->get('username')->getValue(); ?> > Account Detail</h4></div>
        <div class="field_set">
            <div class="field_input">
                <label><?php echo $form->get('username')->getLabel(); ?></label>
                <div class="field"><input type="text" readonly="readonly"value="<?php echo $form->get('username')->getValue(); ?>"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="field_input">
                <label><?php echo $form->get('email')->getLabel(); ?></label>
                <div class="field"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $form->get('email')->getValue(); ?>"></div>
            </div>
        </div>     
        </div>
        <div class="field_set">
            <div class="field_input">
                <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('gender')->setAttribute('class', 'stylish-select')); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field_set">
            <div class="field_input">
                <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('title')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="free-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return validatePassword();"/>
            <input type="button" value="Back" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->url('admin_administrator'); ?>';return false;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
$this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

Any idea on whats getting wrong i can over come this if i use

> $this->formRow()

with all fields but if i use this it will ruin my design requirements.

Comment: try to use a minimal example and strip whats not needed.

Comment: ok stripped lets see if u can understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs don't have a `name` attribute, for example

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $form->get('email')->getValue(); ?>">
```

Should be

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $form->get('email')->getValue(); ?>">
missing------------^
```

Comment: ola nice i guess that is a bit too obvious silly mistake. let me check this